# Appactivate not working for all users

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple Excel program that runs a series of macros, one being an AppActivate command on a firefox window, send keys and then Appactivate to return to itself.

On my laptop it works fine. but when I go to another laptop I get an invalid procedure call error as if it cannot find the named window. Both laptops are running Windows 10 and both are running Excel 2016.

I also edit the application name/caption at the beginning to simplify the window name when the workbook is opened.

```
ActiveWindow.Caption = ""

With Application
  .DisplayAlerts = False
  .Caption = "Image Repackage Tool"
End With
```

And for the activation I just use

```
AppActivate "Image Repackage Tool"
```

I am at a loss for why it works for me on one laptop but not another.

**** Update ****

Tensure this wasn't just a typo or issue with the caption renaming I REM'd out all changes to the Excel caption so that the original caption remains. I also updated the app activate command to:

```
AppActivate Title:=ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption
```

This should eliminate any errors on that front.

So now my code reads

```
AppActivate "Move Samples - Mozilla Firefox"
Application.Wait Now+TimeSerial(0,0,1)
SendKeys declared_variable
SendKeys "~"
AppActivate Title:=ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption
Application.Wait Now+TimeSerial(0,0,1)
```

The error is always Runtime 5 and always highlights the second activation.

Comment: Have you checked that after you edit the application name that it *truly, actually* updated the name?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm more or less stumped on why it would work on one laptop and not another

Comment: why do you use `Application.Caption = "Image Repackage Tool"` to set the window name instead of `ActiveWindow.Caption = "Image Repackage Tool"`?